# relative complement of A in B with functional programming

Tags: javascript

I have to retrieve the values that exist only on Array B, but do not exist on Array A.

From my research, It is called:

> [relative complement of A in B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement)

[image]

Values in the arrays may not be primitives.I need an efficient and functional apporach to this problem.
I have found [lodash `_.without`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#without) function, but it supports only array of primitive numbers.

Array A:

```
[{
    id: 1
},
{
    id:2
}]
```

Array B:

```
[{
    id:2
},
{
    id:3
}]
```

result should be:

```
[{
    id:3
}]
```

this object is the only one who exist on Array B, but not on Array A.

Comment: Your image is even used here: http://www.competa.com/blog/oneliner-set-operations-arrays/ - I found that when googling "relative complement javascript" - just rewrite the filter: `let result = [...new Set(B.filter(item => !A.includes(item)))];`

Comment: yes. however, it solves the problem for primitive numbers (loddash function does it too). i am looking for functional approach with a function that can compare.

Comment: Just rewrite the filter part

Comment: In lodash, there's `._differenceBy/With` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a comparison function which takes two objects and check the `id` for unequalness.

```js
var aa = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    bb = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    comparison = (a, b) => a.id !== b.id,
    result = bb.filter(b => aa.every(a => comparison(a, b)));

console.log(result);
```

With a check for equalness

```js
var aa = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
    bb = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    comparison = (a, b) => a.id === b.id,
    result = bb.filter(b => aa.every(a => !comparison(a, b)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#filter` with `array#some`. Iterate through `arrB` and check if the `arrA` contains that `id` using `array#some` and negate the result of `array#some`.

```js
var arrA = [{id: 1},{id:2}],
    arrB = [{id:2},{id:3}],
    result = arrB.filter(({id}) => !arrA.some(o => o.id === id));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks, however the solution is hard-coded, there's a need for functional solution, it should accept a comparison function :)

Comment: You can wrap this a method passing your comparison criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.filter` and `array.prototype.findIndex`:

```js
var arrayA = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
var arrayB = [{ id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

var result = arrayB.filter(b => arrayA.findIndex(a => a.id === b.id) === -1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use lodash, `_.differenceBy` could be of use:

```
relativeComplementOfAinB = _.differenceBy(arrayB, arrayA, v => v.id);
```